# My Hair Particle system is moving in a weird fashion when I rotate the Head bone. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: animation, particles, hair

----Update-----
The file is too large for stack exchange so I have it in a folder on a google drive. here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1UYLE5okY5VIhOVSiWZYP_suJeuRTd393?usp=drive_link

UPDATE-------
I've narrowed down the issue to these specific Faces, I created a different particle system with just these faces and the problem is only consistant with these faces here. Pretty much any particle that lands on these faces, do not move naturally with the head. Any thoughts?

[image]

------Original------

I have created a hair particle system, well 2. I have the bangs and the rest of the hair separate. The bangs operate just fine with the hair dynamics and it appears that the rest of the hair does too, except when I start moving my character, especially the head. In a neutral pose, the Hair looks to be normal:
[image: Hair in a neutral pose]

But when I begin to rotate my head even a little Certain particles start going off track:
[image: Hair when rotating Head]

I have tried adjusting a milion different settings to no avail. I even tried turning Hair dynamics off and the problem still persists.

Below are my settings, The file is rather large so, Ill only add it if needed.
[image: Settings]
[image: Settings]
[image: Settings]

Comment: Are those problematic faces fully connected to the rest of mesh? Are the face normals orientated correctly? (A sample Blender file with this issue is recommended to upload)

Comment: Yes all faces are oriented correctly. I made a proxy mesh for the hair using only certain faces, and the hair moved normally. But the hair dynamics only worked on part of the pony tail. Honestly I may just move too a different hairstyle, I'm on a dead line. But if anyone can figure it out id be ecstatic!

Comment: Im gonna add a stripped down version to stack exchange for you one sec

Comment: actually the file is 317 mb when stripped down So i can use exchange maybe a google drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of the problem is that you attached your particle hair system on an emitting mesh which is deformed during the animation. The deformed emitting mesh is definitely going to engender weird behaviour on the particle hair.

For example, let's observe the back of the head mesh. Currently, it is all quads in the normal shape.
[image]

Now, in the pose mode, I rotate the neck for about 67.9 degree around the global **z** axis.
[image]

Because of this rotation, the back of head mesh is deformed - the shape of the quads on the back of the head becomes stretched, so that the hair emitted from this mesh behaves weirdly.
[image]

But the front hair bang is still fine, because the front of head mesh is not stretched when the neck is rotated.
[image]

To further demonstrate this, I can make the front hair behave weirdly as well. For example, this is the front head mesh:
[image]

Now, in the Sculpt mode, I am using the brush **Slide Relax** to stretch the quads on the forehead as shown below:
[image]

After the stretch, you see that the front hair bang also starts to behave weirdly:
[image]

The **solution** to this problem is to avoid stretching the emitting mesh during the animation, esp for those emitting mesh which emits long hair. One way to do this is to make a separate emitting mesh. For example, in the Edit mode, I can select part of the head mesh, duplicate the selection, and separate the selection from the head mesh.
[image]

I can use this separate piece of mesh as the new emitting mesh to emit hair particles. Here on the following screenshot, this new emitting mesh has a name "*Rikka Body.001*". And I am using an add-on called "[Any Hair Any Mesh - Hair Utilities](https://blendermarket.com/products/any-hair-any-mesh---hair-transfer-tools)" to quickly transfer the original hair to the new emitting mesh, so that I do not have to spend time to re-create the original hair for the new emitting mesh. Here is the result:
[image]

After the hair particle is made and finalized, I can parent this separate emitting mesh to the head bone for animation. However, please make sure that during the animation the emitting mesh is rigid, and is not subjected to any mesh deformation.

Comment: Thanks Ill have to give it a try and the add-on would be super helpful. I thought maybe i could do this, but I really didnt want to have to regroom the particles!

Comment: How did you use that plug in, I dont think im doing it right, it's transfering the settings but not the particles over to the new proxy mesh

Comment: @JoshuaSonnenfroh To successfully use that add-on, you have to add several pieces of extra meshes before transfer. For example, you can add two cubes, namely, cube 1 and cube 2.  Also, the order of the transfer also matters. My order would be: cube 1, new emitting mesh, cube 2 - meaning transfer hair particles to cube 1 first, then to new emitting mesh second, and to cube 2 last. Also, check its FAQ section: https://blendermarket.com/products/any-hair-any-mesh---hair-transfer-tools/faq